# На что бы заменить одну из "частей"?

Tags: тавтология

> Площадь Республики – часть терм Диоклетиана. Масштабная архитектурная
>   реальность древнего Рима здесь частью сохранилась.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1). Площадь Республики – остаток терм Диоклетиана. Масштабная архитектурная реальность древнего Рима здесь частью сохранилась.

2). Площадь Республики – территория античных терм Диоклетиана. Масштабная архитектурная реальность древнего Рима здесь частью сохранилась.

3). Площадь Республики – бывшие термы Диоклетиана. Масштабная архитектурная реальность древнего Рима здесь частью сохранилась.

Answer (score 1):

> Немного, в некоторой степени, в какой-то степени, фрагментами,
>   неполностью, частично.

Comment: Фрагменты терм? Красиво, но требует одобрения автора.

Answer (score 0):

Площадь Республики – **часть** терм Диоклетиана. Масштабная архитектурная реальность древнего Рима  сохранилась здесь в значительной  степени (здесь особенно впечатляет), так как руины центрального зала терм были перестроены в современные здания (две церкви и и музей).

http://hitplaneta.ru/?p=1083